# Bootstrap 5 navbar doesn't collapse

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I don't know why this isn't working.
I'm using react and bootstrap to create a landing page, in the header component I put a navbar, but it's not collapsing.
My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logonoBG.png';

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <img className="navbar-brand logo" src={logo} alt="#" />
          <button 
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#gallery">Galeria</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#contact">Contato</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the "navbar-toggler" className from the button and get rid of "navbar-collapse" className from navbarSupportedContent. Everything else can stay the same:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Header() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="navbar-brand logo"  alt="#">LOGO</div>
    
            <button 
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#gallery">Galeria</a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="#contact">Contato</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  }
```

However, the behavior will be strange. The navbar seems to have a space-between property for justify-content. When the
navbarSupportedContent is revealed, it will push your button to the center of the navbar. To fix this, just put the button and the navbarSupportedContent into the same div.

The following should work, but adjustments may be necessary depending on what styling you are going for.

```
export default function Header() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="navbar-brand logo"  alt="#">LOGO</div>
            <div>
            <button 
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#gallery">Galeria</a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="#contact">Contato</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I made these changes, but it still doesn't collapse. I don't know if it's a bug in my browser or something else.